# mysql ) How to print using group by, including when count is 0

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

When I have such a table,

[image]

[image]

I want to get the result of a select statement like the picture below.

[image]

However, when count is 0, the row is omitted.

[image]

This makes me confused.
How can I modify this SQL statement to print with count = 0 rows?

```
SELECT ca.syear, COUNT(cc.joined),cc.joined
FROM schedules AS cc JOIN
     schedule_assignment AS ca
     ON ca.idx = cc.assignment
where student = 1 AND  cc.joined = 1
GROUP BY ca.syear;
```

Sorry, my reputation is under 10 so I can't show the image right away. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT sa.syear, COUNT(cc.joined)
FROM schedule_assignment sa LEFT JOIN
     schedules s 
     ON ca.idx = cc.assignment AND
        s.student = 1 AND 
        s..joined = 1
GROUP BY sa.syear;
```

I did not include `join`ed in the result set  It is always `1`, so that does not seem useful.  You can include it:  `1 as joined`, if you really want it.